# Sensibly merging two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

If one of my dataframes gives me some info about items:

```
    itemId     property_1      property_2     property_n       Decision
 0      i1          88.90             NaN              0              1
 1      i2          87.09    7.653800e+06              0              0
 2      i3          78.90    7.623800e+06              1              1
 3      i4          93.02             NaN              1              0
 ...
```

And the other one gives me some info about how users interacted with the items:

```
     userId        itemId      Decision
  0      u1            i1             0
  1      u1            i2             1
  2      u2            i1             1
  3      u2            i3             0
  4      u2            i4             1
  5      u3            i5             0
    ...
```

I am interested in predicting the `Decision`, which is easy to do if I work with each dataframe, separately. **But can I somehow incorporate the second one into the first one**, given that in the second one, each `item` appears multiple times with different `Decisions`?

I would like to have something like:

```
    itemId     property_1      property_2     property_n     u1_decision  ...    Decision
  0     i1          88.90             NaN              0               0               1
  1     i2          87.09    7.653800e+06              0               1               0
  2     i3          78.90    7.623800e+06              1             NaN               1
  4     i4          93.02             NaN              1             NaN               0  
   ...
```

So each user becomes a column, result in something very sparse. The first question would be whether this makes sense, and the second question would be how do I merge the rows from the second dataframe as columns into the first one (I know how to `df.merge` on `Decision`, but this doesn't give me the desired result).

Comment: Since its many to one, you need to create aggregation columns for the item could be sums or frequency, ect ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pivot` the second table like:

```
df.pivot(index='itemId', columns='userId', values='Decision').reset_index()
```

Then you can do the `merge` on `itemId`.

Comment: But now the index column has the name userId, but it does work in the end.

Comment: Yeah funny Pandas indexing.